# How to disable resharper go to implementation

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

when I press f12 I usually can see decompiled code via visual studio. But now when I go to implementation with resharper installed, it shows this

[image]

May I ask if anyone knows how to disable this and revert back to visual studio's go to implementation.

I've tried suggestions here as well, disabled rich mouse navigation and it still doesn't work https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001686139-How-can-I-disable-Resharper-Go-to-Implementation-

Answer (score 0):

In *Tools | Options | Keyboard* you'll be able to bind the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to the VS command rather than the ReSharper one. Search for `Edit.GoToDefinition` and assign that.